# JQGrid Multiple Search Options Blank

Tags: jquery, search, jqgrid, advanced-search

So I'm trying to implement the Multiple Search feature on my site in JQGrid and the box appears fine but non of the drop downs will populate so there are no search options and for fields that have drop down options those will no appear either. Does anyone know why it might be doing this? I have a picture below of what it looks like. Thanks

http://i287.photobucket.com/albums/ll122/PcGuy5239/Untitled.png

Also in case you need it here is the code where I call the advanced search

```
$("#list").jqGrid("searchGrid", {multipleSearch: true, multipleGroup: true, sopt:['eq','ne','cn','bw','bn']});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this url:
http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/operator-edit-in-search-dialog-is-empty-resolved/

Seems you have not update localization scripts, which format was changed on version 4.5.2.